# How to get all the filenames in android directory?

Tags: java, android

Im trying to list all the files in a particular folder of my android emulator and i keep getting null answer.

Heres my code:

```
File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File[] file= new File(sdCardRoot+"path");
for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
    if (f.isFile())
        String name = f.getName();

}
```

This doesnt seem to work dont know why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've split the function in two parts, first function gets all the files in the given path and the second function gets the filenames from the file array.

```
public File[] GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
    File f = new File(DirectoryPath);
    f.mkdirs();
    File[] file = f.listFiles();
    return file;
}

public ArrayList<String> getFileNames(File[] file){
    ArrayList<String> arrayFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
     if (file.length == 0)
            return null;
        else {
            for (int i=0; i<file.length; i++) 
                arrayFiles.add(file[i].getName());
        }

    return arrayFiles;
}
```

Comment: Why using an arraylist if you can use a simple `String` array?

Comment: doesnt really make a difference. Since hes using files he might want to more operations on the list and its easier to do those with arraylist. and i always prefer arraylist over arrays :)

Comment: Shorter:     public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String path){
        ArrayList<String> f_arr = new ArrayList<>();
        File f_path = new File(path);
        File[] files = f_path.listFiles();
        for(File f : files) f_arr.add(f.getName());
        return f_arr;
    }

Answer (score 2):

change

```
File[] file= new File(sdCardRoot+"path");
```

with

```
File[] file= new File(sdCardRoot, "path");
```

and make sure the directory `path` exits

Comment: you will have to use `File.seperator`. try this `File[] file= new File(sdCardRoot+File.seperator+"path")`

Comment: you missed the file separator / so the result string is /mnt/sdcardpath instead of /mnt/sdcard/path. Since file has a Constructor that takes two paramter why do not use it ?

Comment: no i am putting the path starting with the '/' i just wrote path here to make it simple to read. but i got your point, will use the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Just Check this:

```
  List<File> files = getListFiles(new File("YOUR ROOT")); 
  private List<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
      ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
      File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
      for (File file : files) {
          if (file.isDirectory()) {
          inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
      } else {
          if(file.getName().endsWith(".csv")) {
              inFiles.add(file);
          }
      }
}

return inFiles;
```

Comment: inFiles  should not be local variable

Answer (score 0):

Since `sdCardRoot` is instance of `File`, `sdCardRoot+"path"` will return the same thing as `sdCardRoot.toString() + "path"`.

However, calling `file.toString()` returns file name, but not absolute path. You need to call `sdCardRoot.getAbsolutePath() + "path"`.

Also, make sure that you have allowed the emulator to use a certain amount of memory for external storage.